# How to get tab completion for a user defined command in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am writing a small function that takes directory as argument .

```
function! GetDirectoryAndDoSomething(default)
         :let directory = input('Directory: ', a:default)
         "Call Some Function
endfunction
```

This works fairly well if I call GetDirectoryAndDoSomething('.') , however as it is a string input , there is no Tab Completion for directories . How can I actually get the tab compleition working for directory as a user input ?

Comment: Read `:h :command-completion` you probably want `-complete=dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `-complete=dir` for your command.

Example:

```
command -nargs=+ -complete=dir Blah :echo "<args>"
```

This will echo whatever the user puts as an argument to `Blah` but more importantly it will tab complete any part of the the argument to be directories.

To find out more read `:h :command-completion`